# Not in list - List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

How can I add a condition in list comprehension like this? Ex:

Ex:

```
[dict if dict not in THIS.LIST for dict in tempList]
```

Comment: Don't worry bro. I've already sent a screenshot to your professor.

Comment: Asking for help on parts of a question is not equivalent to asking for a solution to a problem. It's the same as asking for help on creating a list comprehension when it is part of a much bigger problem. I just undo the deletion on the post. I just don't like seeing it in my asked questions knowing that someone was rude enough to respond with vulgar invectives instead of a proper response.

Comment: I'm referring to the question you deleted, not this question. You even posted the source of your question. It came from a pdf titled quiz #4. At the top, it referred an academic integrity statement that you all signed (in class, presumably). You were asking for help on that question on stackoverflow. This looks like a blatant example of cheating to me. Don't worry, I didn't actually email your professor. In the future, just please respect the other students in the classroom and don't try ask for help from the stackoverflow community specifically on problems from your graded quiz.

Answer (score 4):

You had the order wrong, move the if to the end.

```
[dict for dict in tempList if dict not in THIS.LIST ]
```

Using your method python expects an else:

```
[dict if dict not in THIS.LIST else whatever for dict in tempList]
```

If you want to refer to the actual list you are creating use a for loop, if the items were hashable you could use a set to check if the element had already been seen  with `0(1)` lookups but if you have dicts then you won't be able to use a set with the dict directly:

```
res = [] 
for dct in temp_list:
    if dct not in res:
        res.append(dct)
```

Or a similar approach using a list comp, check from start of the list to the current index:

```
print([dct for ind, dct in enumerate(temp_list) if dct not in temp_list[:ind]])
```

If you just want to remove duplicate dicts we can use the `dict.items`:

```
temp_list = [ {1:2},{1:2}]
print([dict(items) for items in set(tuple(dct.items()) for dct in temp_list) ])
```

Or use an `OrderedDict` to keep order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
temp_list = [ {1:2},{1:2}]

print(list(OrderedDict(((tuple(dct.items()),dct) for dct in temp_list)).values()))
```

Or again use a normal loop:

```
temp_list = [ {1:2},{1:2}]
seen = set()
out = []
for dct in temp_list:
    tup = tuple(dct.items())
    if tup not in seen:
        out.append(dct)
        seen.add(tup)
print(out)
```

Comment: What if you wanted to refer to the list that was being created by comprehension itself?

Comment: @Xari There is no clean way to do that with a list comprehension. You can find hacky, implementation specific methods with a bit of googling, but, quite frankly, you normally shouldn't. Either use a different data structure, such as a `set`, or a `for` loop.

Comment: Ah ok you want to check the current list as items are added? You cannot do that using a list comp. You would need  a normal loop appending and checking, if you have actual dicts in the list you cannot use a set.